# MediaElement loses its source / buffered input when removed from Visual Tree

Tags: c#, windows-8, mediaelement

I am building a media player for my app from scratch. In order to go from "regular" view to fullscreen, the player is removed from one part of my XAML and inserted into another - like this:

```
if (Trailer.IsFullScreen())
{
    // some code here

    var mediaPlayer = Trailer; // Trailer is the media player usercontrol
    TrailerFullScreenGrid.Children.Remove(Trailer);
    TrailerWrapper.Children.Add(mediaPlayer);

    // more code here
}
else
{
     // some code here

     var mediaPlayer = Trailer;
     TrailerWrapper.Children.Remove(Trailer);
     TrailerFullScreenGrid.Children.Add(mediaPlayer);

     // more code here
 }
```

Now, when I do this, the video doesn't continue playback, and if you click the play button, it restarts the entire clip. What I would like is to have pause the movie, do all my xaml magic and then continue playback from whenever it was paused. I've read something about UnloadedBehaviour, but that doesn't seem to be a possibility in Windows 8 RTM.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some visual elements have to remain in the visual tree to work correctly, especially ones having to with media playback or capture. I've never tried what you're doing but it doesn't surprise me that this is the behavior.

I suppose you could capture the playback position and try to set it after re-parenting the control and starting playback again, but that's a lot of work and could be error prone. Truthfully, the way the Windows developers intended for you to deal with this sort of scenario is by using Visual States.

You may have come across Visual States before if you've worked with **LayoutAwarePage** in Expression Blend. **LayoutAwarePage** has states for all of the different view modes in Windows 8 (Filled, Snapped, Full Landscape, Full Portrait). But you can always create your own states even if you don't use **LayoutAwarePage**. You create states on the States tab in Blend (Window -> States if you don't see that window).

Every state must reside in a state *group*. The group name doesn't matter but just understand that every state in a group is exclusive. So you could call your group **MediaPlaybackStates** and inside that group put two states called **Windowed** and **FullScreen**.

One you've defined the two states you can use Blend to design them. You just select the state and change any properties you want. Then at runtime when you tell the framework to go to that state it plays back your “recorded” changes and can even animate them for you.

Of course one problem is that you can’t change the parent of a control using a Visual State. Instead, consider grouping all of the controls around your player into panels that can be collapsed when you go into “FullScreen” mode. Use the **Grid** control to lay everything out and make sure the **Row** / **Cell** that the player is in are set to “*” sizing. That means it will take up all the available space when the other controls are collapsed.

I have a detailed article on my blog that shows how to use Visual States to deal with the various Windows 8 window states (Filled, Snapped, etc.). That article should hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

http://jaredbienz.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/wp-to-w8-view-states-using-visual-state-manager/

When you're ready to change the state at runtime, call

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "FullScreen", true);
```

The first parameter (*this*) means we're changing the state of the entire window. The second parameter is the name of the state we want to switch to and the last parameter is whether or not you want to use transitions (or animations) if they're present in the state.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Comment: Great answer @Jared. I'll try this out in the morning and comment / accept your answer as appropriate. Thank you for sharing your knowledge! :-)

Comment: This worked perfectly - and SO much easier than what I formerly had. Thanks, and all the kudos I can give you!

Comment: AWESOME! Yeah, I really like Visual States. Its unfortunate so many people don't know they exist, but once you have them they solve some complex problems easily. BTW, Visual States are how controls change their appearance too. For example, Button has visual states for MouseOver, Pressed, etc. They're all editable when you edit the controls style. Rock on!